# How to download file from other repo to current repo in workflow file (github actions)

Tags: github, curl, github-actions, workflow, wget

suppose the workflow file in repo1 has

```
- name: Import
        run: |

           wget https://github.com/kpnssreeram/resuseworkflow-composite/blob/main/hello.env
```

here it is importing **hello.env **from other repository to current runner
the hello.env contains
`name=hello`

What happens is it was downloading as expected, but the contents in it are changing like this instead of name

[log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYP0L.png)

I need a solution so that same file should be downloaded here without changing anything
I am sharing the workflow link.
Anyone please resolve this.
link to Github action file
[workflow](https://github.com/kpnssreeram/envvariablesimpfile/actions/runs/8128420200/workflow)